# How to store the id and names in arry list using asp.net enter the name Using auto complete ajax tool, so select the name pass the id to db?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am using Asp.net, C#.net and sql server. my Issue is user enter the name in textbox automatically scrolling the name (**i am using Autocomplete tool in ajax and web services**) but names only display **but i have select the name particular id pass the database in storing purpose** , how it possible i am using list get the names only  any one help me
my code is
**Autocomplete.asmx page**

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
        {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            count = 10;
        }
        DataTable dt = GetRecords(prefixText);
        List<string> items = new List<string>(count);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string strName = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            items.Add(strName);
        }
        return items.ToArray();
    }

    public DataTable GetRecords(string strName)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Usp_Consultant", LITRMSConnection);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@consultantname", strName);
                DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        LITRMSConnection.Open();
        dAdapter.Fill(objDs);
        LITRMSConnection.Close();
        return objDs.Tables[0];
    }
```

Stored procedure is

```
CREATE Procedure Usp_Consultant
    (@consultantname varchar(100))
As
    Begin

            select (FirstName+LastName)as ConsultantName from Consultant  where FirstName like '%'+@consultantname+'%'      
            union all           
            select(Firstname+LastName)as consultantName from InDirectConsultant i where FirstName  like '%'+@consultantname+'%' 
            ORDER BY 1;
        End
```

but i have id also like this

```
select Consid, (FirstName+LastName)as ConsultantName from Consultant  where FirstName like '%'+@consultantname+'%'
```

**Consid is Varchar.**

Thank u
hemanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return a json object back from your webservivce that includes the name and the ID, and when the user selects the name, using the autocompleteselect event, grab the ID and put it in a hidden field on the page.

You will then have this ID when you post back the page.

Comment: if u dont mine pls give me some idea of that code based on my code